# Make XML output

Tags: xml, ocaml

I have coded a tool, at the moment the output of the tool is in `text` format. For example, here are printing functions:

```
(* in Shelf.ml *)
let print (chan: out_channel) (x: t) : unit =
  Printf.fprintf chan "Shelf:";
  List.iter (Book.print chan "%a\n") x

(* in Book.ml *)
let print (chan: out_channel) (x: t) : unit =
  Printf.fprintf chan "Book: %s, %d, %s" x.name x.year x.abstract
```

Here is an output example as `text`:

```
Shelf:
Book: LOTR, 1954, begin end
Book: The Hobbit, 1937, nice book
```

Now I decide to also output `XML` format. The advantage of that, I guess, is to have a better communication with other tools that take my output as input. For instance, I may need to show my output as a webpage; or some GUI may take my output and make a better layout.

So an output example as `XML` looks as follows:

```
<shelf>
    <book name="LOTR">
        <year>1954</year>
        <abstract>begin end</abstract>
    </book>
    <book name="The Hobbit">
        <year>1937</year>
        <abstract>nice book</abstract>
    </book>
</shelf>
```

My question is, how should I develop the OCaml programs to make this kind of `XML` output? Should I add for example to each module `print_xml` that hard-code tags as string?

People point me to [Xmlm](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm) and [Markup](https://github.com/aantron/markup.ml). Should I use these modules instead of hard-coding my string tags? What are the advantages to use these modules?

Comment: how you develop is up to you? Its kind of hard to see the coding question here, like you're asking if you should use a library but that's not specific to OCaml, that's a general thing for all langs.

Comment: The question is about "what are the advantages of using these two modules in comparison with hard-coding?". People who know these modules would not consider the question too general, and would have some precise elements to contribute...

Comment: Here's one subjective answer then. I've used both. Markup is easier to understand and work with.

Comment: OK... Then what is the advantage of using Markup in comparaison with hard-coding, with regard to the requirements in my OP?

Comment: Umm that you're using a library instead of doing it yourself?? I'm not sure what answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, especially if your structure is not complex and You don't want to rely on external library dependencies at all costs.

However, even in the simplest case (formatting-related only, without touching namespaces, schemas, etc.) the library will give you:

**1. Automatic tag closing**

```
Printf.fprintf "<tagname>%s</tagname>" x
```

as well as

```
print_string "<foo>"
...
print_string "</foo>"
```

looks wrong and is error-prone.

```
out `El_start tag
...
out `El_end
```

is so much nicer :)

Also You will likely want

```
<tag/>
```

instead of

```
<tag></tag>
```

**2. Automatic indentation for pretty printing**

**3. Compact/indented output**

Comment: Thank you... Could you please explain a little bit more about `indentation`? I am looking for automatic indentation solution... The document of `Markup` has few examples...

Comment: I've not used `Markup` personally, sorry. In `Xmlm` however, it is just a matter of passing `Some x` as a labeled argument `indent` to `make_output` function (default is `None` i.e. no indentation): [the link](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm/doc/Xmlm.html#outindent).

Comment: @SoftTimur it's belated, but for automatic indentation in Markup.ml, pass the signals through `pretty_print`. So, e.g. `signals |> pretty_print |> to_string`. I'll write an example in some days, for reference of future users.